# Best Fit with linear function and a problem of "zero"

Tags: experimental-physics, computational-physics, error-analysis, software, data-analysis

I have experimental data on the dependence of the magnetic field (B) in the center of the [Helmholtz coils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil) on the current in it(I).

```
I(A)  B(Tl)   I_error B_error
1.000 0.73e-3 0.02 0.04e-3
1.125 0.80e-3 0.02 0.04e-3
1.250 0.82e-3 0.02 0.04e-3
1.375 0.91e-3 0.02 0.03e-3
1.500 1.05e-3 0.02 0.03e-3
1.625 1.09e-3 0.02 0.03e-3
1.750 1.15e-3 0.02 0.03e-3
1.875 1.32e-3 0.02 0.03e-3
2.000 1.35e-3 0.02 0.02e-3
2.125 1.46e-3 0.02 0.02e-3
2.250 1.55e-3 0.02 0.02e-3
```

The theory predicts a linear dependence between these quantities of the form $B = C \cdot I$ (i.e. $y = ax$). Fitting on the linear model $y = ax$ of this data, I get the value of the parameter (a or C) $C = (6.83 \pm 0.05) \cdot 10^{-4}$ Tl/A.

But, when I try to use model $y = ax + b$ (with nonzero $b$), I get $C = (6.83 \pm 0.24) \cdot 10^{-4}$ Tl/A with value $b = 0.013\cdot 10^{-4}$ and with huge standart deviation $\Delta b = 0.46 \cdot 10^{-4}$ (i.e. $b \ll \Delta b$).

Thus, the question arises, in which case I got the correct error in the `a` parameter, when i used a model $y = ax + b$ ($\Delta a = 0.24 \cdot 10^{-4}$) or a model $y = ax$ ($\Delta a = 0.05 \cdot 10^{-4}$)?

---

$C = (6.83 \pm 0.05) \cdot 10^{-4}$ Tl/A

or

$C = (6.83 \pm 0.24) \cdot 10^{-4}$ Tl/A

### ?

[image]
Fitting program is `GnuPlot` (GpFit.gp):

```
# ------------ Fitting ----------
set fit quiet
a = 6e-4;
f(x) = a*x + b; 
set fit errorvariables;
fit f(x) ARG1 u 1:2:3:4  xyerrors via a,b; 

# ------ Calculation of R^2 ------

stats "" u 2:($2 - (a*$1 + b)) nooutput
SST = STATS_stddev_x**2*STATS_records
SSE = STATS_sumsq_y
R2 = 1 - SSE/SST
 
# ------- Results ----------

set print ARG2
print "Parameter a: ", a
print "Standart Deviation of a: ", a_err
print "Parameter b: ", b
print "Standart Deviation of b: ", b_err
print "chi square: ", (FIT_STDFIT)**2
print "R square:" , R2
```

To start script use

```
gnuplot -persist -c GnuFit.gp <input_data_file> <output_results_file>
```

Comment: If you believe $b = 0$ and only want to measure the value of $a$, use the first. If you want to experimentally test whether $b = 0$ as well, use the second.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Ok, suppose I want to experimentally test whether b=0 as well, and I use the second, then I get b << Delta b, what should I conclude?

Comment: The conclusion would be that b is indistinguishable from zero.

Answer (score 2):

Once you set the origin as a data point without any error, ie the best fit graph **must** go through through the origin you limit the number of possible lines that fit the data as compared with the more general case of assuming it to be a linear relationship.

One thing which is not immediately obvious from your graph is that the lowest value data point is a long way from the origin when compared with the range of the data points.
Including the origin shows this clearly but note the best fit line shown below weighted each of the data points equally.

[image]

When you did the experiment did you check if there was a zero error in the magnetic field and current measuring devices?  An offset would result in a graph which does not got through the origin although theory predicts a direct proportionality.

Comment: "Did the experiment did you check if there was a zero error in the magnetic field and current measuring devices?" Yes, I checked. To obtain one point, I took ten readings, each time returning the current to zero and again raising it to the desired one.

Answer (score 2):

The uncertainty of the fit parameters is specific to the used fitting model. So the question is not, which uncertainty is correct, but which model should be used. In statistics there are tools for model selection (e.g. cross-validation, penalties for each fit-parameter), as well as for "data point selection for fits". I reckon the data point selection is more appropriate for your example.Thus, I am going to elaborate on this in the following.

One property which is usually considered when performing fits is the so called **leverage**. It is an important, because if we fit with constants weights (each data point obtains the same weight) the data points do not influence the fit equally. Thus, if we add a data point at $(I,B)=(0,0)$, this new data point is highly influential on the fit. As Farcher pointed out, this is what you effectively do by selecting the model $y=a x$.

Coming back to your original question, I recommend that you use the model $y = a x + b$, because you obtain larger uncertainties. From my perspective it is important that we are "**conservative**", because unknown errors usually are present. E.g. a proper measurement system analysis consists of many studies (gauge R&R, bias, linearity, and stability) of the measurement device. Since this is not often performed, we should not be over confident in our results.

Comment: “I recommend that you use the model =+, because you obtain larger uncertainties. From my perspective it is important that we are "conservative". I had never thought of it that way, but that is a great way to look at it